# How to get the value of input tag onSubmit without using onChange in React js/Typescript?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, onsubmit

I have no other special events onChange so I need to simplify my code by only handling events onSubmit specifically on the Form tag.

I'm creating a simple *Form* in Typescript in React and When I click **Submit**, I want to log the value of the *input* box in the console. But I get an error when I do this.

```
import React from "react";

const handleSubmit =(event:React.FormEvent<HTMLFormElement>) =>{
    event.preventDefault();
    console.log(event.currentTarget[0].value);
  };

export const InputForm: React.FC  = () =>{
    return (
        <form className='form-container' onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
            <input className="input" placeholder="Enter value" required />
            <button type="submit">Enter</button>
          </form>  
      )
}
```

My reasoning for this line => `console.log(event.currentTarget[0].value);` is that the form tag has 2 elements, input and button, so `event.currentTarget[0]` alone returns the input tag in the console but it passes an error(**Property 'value' does not exist on type 'Element'.ts(2339)**) when i try to add `.value`

Comment: This works fine for me, try with event.target[0].value;
And also, setting a react component to the type FC is not needed, I guess you could call it redundant. Same as setting a type of a state to a primary value, you let typescript define the type.

Comment: The code itself works, the error is related to typescript in this case. One way to go about this would be to assert it as an input `console.log((event.currentTarget[0] as HTMLInputElement).value);`. But maybe there is a better type for `event` here in the first place.

Comment: I would suggest to maybe avoid this though. While it does result in less code, it works under the assumption that the first element in the `<form>` is indeed the input. Hence, you will need to adjust the whole thing even if you decide to put a simple `<label>` above the input. If you don't need to reflect a UI change then there is no real reason to maintain a `state`, but you can use a `ref` and get the value from there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The usual thing here is to use a controlled component, but you've said you don't want to do that.

The problem is that `event.currentTarget[0]` is just of type `Element`, and `Element` doesn't have `value` (which is just on certain elements, like `HTMLInputElement`, `HTMLSelectElement`, etc.).

**You** know it's an `Element` subtype with `value`, but TypeScript doesn't, because not all form control elements have `value` (`fieldset` and `object` don't, for a start, but they're counted as [form elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement/elements)).

You can put a utility assertion function in your toolkit:

```typescript
function assertIsFormFieldElement(element: Element): asserts element is HTMLInputElement | HTMLSelectElement | HTMLButtonElement {
// Customize this list as necessary −−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    if (!("value" in element)) {
        throw new Error(`Element is not a form field element`);
    }
}
```

...then use it:

```typescript
const handleSubmit = (event: React.FormEvent<HTMLFormElement>) =>{
    event.preventDefault();
    const firstField = event.currentTarget[0];
    assertIsFormFieldElement(firstField);
    console.log(firstField.value);
};
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDG8BmUIjgIilQ3wG4AoczAVwDsNgJa4UBnVpWASVYDFoQvYEgA2AEwCiIpCCS0YAClEy5MAFxwpK+QEoNbDrFZxls+XGDGAEgBUAsgBkutMNRhaz8AD5xbjgMrKGB6qcD5+DgBCbjBMIeYA3uRwKRaYcAoAhAr4AG4oItRI+BbMpqo6OnBJqbVwMAAWOADucLRIrRJQOFAKAAbx8JZtEPAocJgCE8LiJtKefToUtQC+5GvkaEys8A0otGLS-tQARiDA8AC8GUi5qhrI6DAAdPxQIBJ38gA8EW8f81UAD4qpcgTVUrdVM8wEQvjAACJITAoagiRRLZKpLa0HbTKA7ISiMRwa5Q+TPNDUbqqGwoKAAcyQMAA2gAGAC6y1SBk4MB4-yJ4kGCkwwAJMCFYkxtRxrAg0meIggDNF4sJMzEz3yhSQmJWFHISAAHpBYHA5fBnK5JQIHsQXrwAMIpa4KUHgrEpIgwanMBReurfSbvC0iAwAORQskuAHIQyAALQ4mAoYDtKCxuBMY5nC6XBJ7A5HU7nGArIGBuqpb7pm1hyPRpCXfB1twlMDhtBIBoKsScFsSeScOA6oolIgAR2o4qQJIA9JXq9XvicYkx6gBPMDN-CsUsXfBAocwTjfedrmCxWhL5cpc8JoEpKtwfWkIA)

---

Side note: If you're going to do this, you might consider putting a `name` on the input and using that when looking up the element, rather than assuming the `input` will be the first element:

```html
<input name="the-name" className="input" placeholder="Enter value" required />
```

Then you can use a utility function to get the named item from the form:

```typescript
function getFormControl(form: HTMLFormElement, name: string): HTMLInputElement | HTMLSelectElement | HTMLButtonElement /* | ...*/ {
    const control = form.elements.namedItem(name);
    if (!control || control instanceof RadioNodeList || !("value" in control)) {
        throw new Error(`Form control "${name}" not found or was a RadioNodeList`);
    }
    return control;
} 

// ...


const handleSubmit = (event: React.FormEvent<HTMLFormElement>) =>{
    event.preventDefault();
    const inputField = getFormControl(event.currentTarget, "the-name");
    console.log(inputField.value);
};
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDG8BmUIjgIilQ3wG4AoczAVwDsNgJa4BzJGAMWhAGEmYcAGwAUmbgC44ACQAqAWQAyXKCACigpCCS0YAGji0UWyQGcBwWiwCUk2YoCStMNRjrN2+AB9p8hQGUkDQw3LR04bzsFACEXGCYQjzgAegAqcLgAOiyUpLgAb3I4Irg0JjMS-iE4AF44MRUMwPcdEwzDLQATexhNYXakKwpiuGBMOGEAQlKdKs9vaYEIQRHaMxR6JAgxhBQOxgA5CA6kBWByubgJ4XwANxRBaiR8FYqZpasrfMLh4pgACxwAHcDEhgaooDgoMIAAbKPALKr4AAkeX6AF9nrQIFgIHQOnBoHBASgTHAUIhdgcjiczjBoYNvkU0Yy4EQYNQoMwEUsKGi4JRpuU-usOho-NQAEYgYDwWrCJA3DySZDoGAZOGqRU6AA8kQ1GlCMAAfJ9qkaCsMFR4MmAiFqYAARJCYFDUQQwYQM4aC+AWZycYCBfG1Nicbh8N4iK06DJoDlEHQyFBQUP6fAmXDsP4WFj4L3FQVLJAZQQQFjCP0uDiBwQdDJ3B4DXkUchIAAekFgr3Kjn9cOVxDVHB4RTlpvNLLZHOYwhZw219XhghJJn2RiQ1QA5IuALQLFAWJBQTcE2jiqUy6p5YW0UVIc-SmBoo1zn5FbWV+BoZcmVfr6r4J+zxgMuaBIH8SzHFAAGqDoR5wA2jzPEQACO1DAEQ+JJC+b5vtqEqxEwcAwAAnmAG7ppKj74EasE9FA2pJARMBxLQOG4e+SSLkaRSvgyaKkEAA)